# I need to make a non-scrollable Gridview with itemBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to create a grid view inside a listview. It is now being nested and not working well. I want to make it GridView because I want itemBuilder to view the list in Map with index.

Like this

```
return GridView.builder(
      shrinkWrap: false,
      primary: false,
      itemCount: kadakkalproducts.length,
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return SingleProdc(
          product_name: kadakkalproducts[index]['name'],
          product_picture: kadakkalproducts[index]['picture'],
          product_price: kadakkalproducts[index]['price'],
          product_image1: kadakkalproducts[index]['image1'],
          product_image2: kadakkalproducts[index]['image2'],
          product_des: kadakkalproducts[index]['des'],
          product_det: kadakkalproducts[index]['det'],
        );
      },
    );
```

I have used shrinkwrap and primary to stop nested loop. But it doesn't work.

Please help me out to stop scrolling in GridView

Comment: If you don't want your GridView to scroll you can set the ```physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()```. This option is available for almost all scrolls in flutter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add this line inside your GridView**

```
physics:NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()
```

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollPhysics-class.html

Comment: I have tried doing this, but its not what I want..Now the grid view is not scrolling, and the since the gridview is above the listview I also cant scroll my listview...why